# How to share memory from an HDF5 dataset with a NumPy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am writing an application for streaming data from a sensor, and then processing the data in various ways. These processing components include visualizing the data, some number crunching (linear algebra), and also writing the data to disk in an HDF5 format. Ideally each of these components will be its own module, all run in the same Python process so that IPC is not an issue. This leads me to the question of how to efficiently store the streaming data.

The datasets are quite large (~5Gb), and so I would like to minimize the number of copies of the data in memory by sharing it between the components that need access. If all components used straight `ndarray`s, then this should be straightforward: give one of the processes the data, then give everyone else a copy using `ndarray.view()`.

However, the component writing data to disk stores the data in an HDF5 `Dataset`. These are interoperable with `ndarray`s in lots of ways, but it doesn't appear that creating a `view()` works as with `ndarrary`s.

Observe with `ndarray`s:

```
>>> source = np.zeros((10,))
>>> view = source.view()
>>> source[0] = 1
>>> view[0] == 1
True
>>> view.base is source
True
```

However, this doesn't work with HDF5 `Dataset`s:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> file = h5py.File('source.h5', 'a')
>>> source_dset = file.create_dataset('source', (10,), dtype=np.float64)
>>> view_dset = source_dset.value.view()
>>> source_dset[0] = 1
>>> view_dset[0] == 1
False
>>> view_dset.base is source_dset.value
False
```

It also doesn't work to just assign the `Dataset.value` itself, not a `view` of it.

```
>>> view_dset = source_dset.value
>>> source_dset[0] = 2
>>> view_dset[0] == 2
False
>>> view_dset.base is source_dset.value
False
```

So my question is this: **Is there a way to have an `ndarray` share memory with an HDF5 `Dataset`, just as two `ndarray`s can share memory?**

My guess is that this is unlikely to work, probably because of some subtlety in how HDF5 stores arrays in memory. But it is a bit confusing to me, especially that `type(source_dset.value) == numpy.ndarray` and the `OWNDATA` flag of `Dataset.value.view()` is actually `False`. Who owns the memory that the `view` is interpreting?

Version details: Python 3, NumPy version 1.9.1, h5py version 2.3.1, HDF5 version 1.8.13, Linux.

Other details: HDF5 file is chunked.

**EDIT**:

After playing around with this a bit more, it seems like one possible solution is to give other components a reference to the HDF5 `Dataset` itself. This doesn't seem to copy any memory (at least not according to `top`), and changes in the source `Dataset` are reflected in the view.

```
>>> import h5py
>>> file = h5py.File('source.h5', 'a')
>>> source = file.create_dataset('source', (10,), dtype=np.float64)
>>> class Container():
    ...    def __init__(self, source_dset):
    ...        self.dset = source_dset
    ...
>>> container = Containter(source)
>>> source[0] = 1
>>> container.dset[0] == 1
True
```

I'm reasonably happy with this solution (as long as the memory savings pan out), but I'm still curious why the `view` approach above doesn't work.

Comment: Be aware that you make take a huge performance hit passing around the dataset object.

Comment: Further, accessing a dataset does not load all of it into memory at once which allows you to pull out just a sub-set of the dataset at minimal memory cost.  Further, if your data is chunked, it may not even be contiguous in the file (and could even be compressed).  The ability to to arbitrary hyberslab selection is one of the main features of hdf5 and hiding those details is one of the main features of h5py.

Comment: @tcaswell To clarify the data is indeed chunked and compressed, and so is most likely *not* contiguous in the file. So I guess you're right, that any given chunk may or may not exist in memory, so an `ndarray` must copy the data instead of referencing it. Then why does it not own its data? Also, what is the performance hit you're thinking of?

Comment: compare `np.sum(data_set)` to `np.sum(data_set[:])`

Comment: `.value` is a property of the `Dataset`, the array produced by some `getter` function.  So one call to `.value` may not produce the same object as the next.

Comment: @tcaswell I see no time difference between `np.sum(data_set)`, `np.sum(data_set[:])`, and `data_set.sum()`. What point were you trying to get across? @hpaulj You're right, different calls to `Dataset.value` give different objects...why? I can't see any indication in the docs for `h5py` or for `property`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't share memory between a `numpy` array and an `h5py` dataset.  While they have similar API (at least when it comes to indexing), they don't have a compatible memory layout.  In fact, apart from sort of cache, the dataset isn't even in memory - it's on the file.

---

First, I don't see why you need to use `source.view()` with a `numpy` array.  Yes, when selecting from an array or reshaping an array, `numpy` tries to return a `view` as opposed to a copy.  But most (all?) examples of `.view` involve some sort of transformation, such as with a `dtype`.  Can you point to code or documentation example with just `.view()`?

I don't have much experience with `h5py`, but its documentation talks about it providing a thin ndarray-like wrapper around `h5` file objects.  Your `DataSet` is not an `ndarray`.  For example it lacks many of the `ndarray` methods, including `view`.

But indexing a `DataSet` returns an `ndarray`, e.g. `view_dset[:]`.  So does `.value`.  The first part of its documentation (via `view_dset.value??` in `IPython`):

```
Type:            property
String form:     <property object at 0xb4ee37d4>
Docstring:       Alias for dataset[()] 
...
```

Note that when you assign new values to the DataSet you have to index `source_dset` directly.  Indexing the value does not work - except to modify the array.  It doesn't change the file object.

And creating a dataset from an array does not link them any tighter:

```
x = np.arange(10)
xdset = file.create_dataset('x', data=x)
x1 = xdset[:]
```

`x`, `xdset` and `x1` are all independent - changing one does not change the others.

Regarding the times, compare

```
timeit np.sum(x)  #  11.7 µs
timeit np.sum(xdset) # 203 µs
timeit xdset.value #  173 µs
timeit np.sum(x1)  # same as for x
```

The `sum` of an array is much faster than for a dataset.  Most of the extra time is involved in creating an array from the dataset.

Comment: Agreed. Book on `h5py` and the source indicate indexing operations fill a new `ndarray` with data from the file. And I wanted to do this to prevent any copying, since there are many readers but only one writer. But you're point is well-taken, that I might be better off just letting NumPy deal with viewing/copying.