# How do I lazily concatenate "numpy ndarray"-like objects for sequential reading?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, h5py

I have a list of several large hdf5 files, each with a 4D dataset. I would like to obtain a concatenation of them on the first axis, as in, an array-like object that would be used as if all datasets were concatenated. My final intent is to sequentially read chunks of the data along the same axis (e.g. `[0:100,:,:,:]`, `[100:200,:,:,:]`, ...), multiple times.

Datasets in h5py share a significant part of the numpy array API, which allows me to call [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to get the job done:

```
files = [h5.File(name, 'r') for name in filenames]
X = np.concatenate([f['data'] for f in files], axis=0)
```

On the other hand, the memory layout is not the same, and memory cannot be shared among them ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409512/how-to-share-memory-from-an-hdf5-dataset-with-a-numpy-ndarray)). Alas, `concatenate` will eagerly copy the entire content of each array-like object into a new array, which I cannot accept in my use case. The [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e00b9587052248486a9bf66c2ce95638c0d9817f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L320) of the array concatenation function confirms this.

How can I obtain a concatenated view over multiple array-like objects, *without* eagerly reading them to memory? As far as this view is concerned, slicing and indexing over this view would behave just as if I had a concatenated array.

I can imagine that writing a custom wrapper would work, but I would like to know whether such an implementation already exists as a library, or whether another solution to the problem is available and just as feasible. My searches so far have yielded nothing of this sort. I am also willing to accept solutions specific to h5py.

Answer (score 0):

`flist = [f['data'] for f in files]` is a list of `dataset` objects.  The actual data is on the `h5` files, is accessible as long as those files remain open.

When you do

```
arr = np.concatenate(flist, axis=0)
```

I imagine `concatenate` first does

```
tmep = [np.asarray(a) for a in flist]
```

that is, construct a list of numpy arrays.  I assume `np.asarray(f['data'])` is the same as `f['data'].value` or `f['data'][:]` (as I discussed 2 yrs ago in the linked SO question).  I should do some time tests comparing that with

```
arr = np.concatenate([a.value for a in flist], axis=0)
```

`flist` is a kind of lazy compilation of these data sets, in that the data still resides on the file, and is accessed only when you do something more.

```
[a.value[:,:,:10] for a in flist]
```

would load a portion of each of those data sets into memory; I expect that a concatenate on that list would be the equivalent of `arr[:,:,:10]`.

Generators or generator comprehensions are a form of lazy evaluation, but I think they have to be turned into lists before use in `concatenate`.  In any case, the result of `concatenate` is always an array with all the data in a contiguous block of memory.  It is never blocks of data residing in files.

You need to tell us more about what intend to do with this large concatenated array of data sets.  As outline I think you can construct arrays that contain slices of all the data sets.  You could also perform other actions as I demonstrate in the previous answer - but with an access time cost.

Comment: I have updated the question. What I called the intended concatenation would be a view over the array-like objects, which would definitely not use numpy's `concatenate`.

Comment: `[100:200,:,:,:]` apply to the concatenated sets, just one dataset, or a range of 'rows' that overlap two sets?

Comment: Updated again. As far as this view is concerned, slices and index operations over this view would behave just as if I had a concatenated array. I can't think of a way to make this clearer.

Comment: I think you need to write your own book keeping function that calculates which slices of which datasets it loads and concatenates.  Look in `np.lib.index_tricks` if you want ideas on how to cast such a function as a class that accepts indexing notation.  I can sketch such function if needed.