# h5py: How to index over multiple large HDF5 files without loading all their content into memory

Tags: python, h5py

This is a question about working with multiple HDF5 datasets simultaneously while treating them as one dataset as far as possible.

I have multiple `.h5` files, each of which contains tens of thousands of images. Let's call the files

```
file01.h5
file02.h5
file03.h5
```

I now want to create a list or array that contains "pointers" to all images of all three files, without actually loading the images.

Here is what I have so far:

I first open all files:

```
file01 = h5py.File('file01.h5', 'r')
file02 = h5py.File('file02.h5', 'r')
file03 = h5py.File('file03.h5', 'r')
```

and add their image datasets to a list:

```
images = []
images.append(file01['images'])
images.append(file02['images'])
images.append(file03['images'])
```

where `file01['images']` is an HDF5 dataset of shape e.g. `(52722, 3, 160, 320)`, i.e. 52722 images. All good so far, none of the content has been loaded into memory yet. Now I want to make these three separate image lists into one so that I can work with it as if it were one large dataset. I tried to do this:

```
images = np.concatenate(images)
```

This is where it breaks. As soon as I concatenate the three HDF5 datasets, it actually loads the images as Numpy arrays and I run out of memory.

What would be the best way to solve this?

I need a solution that allows me to Numpy-slice and index into the three datasets as if it were one.

For example, assume each dataset contained 50,000 images and I wanted to load the third image of each dataset, I need a list `images` that allows me to index those images as

```
batch = images[[2, 50002, 100002]]
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to concatenate datasets "out of memory" in the way you want. What you can do is create one large dataset from the 3 smaller ones in a separate file. And then query the larger file out of memory. Is this a possible solution for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jp_data_analysis! You're probably right and it's not possible, but unfortunately creating one large dataset in a separate file is not ideal because of the large disk space overhead it would require (the individual files are still needed, too). I guess I'll just have to keep the datasets separate and do a bunch of ugly index conversions every time I want to access an item in one of them.

Comment: Yes, that may be your only option. What I would suggest is to create some basic functions to do the ugly indexing transformations.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I'll do that, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Similar discussion without accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572696/how-do-i-lazily-concatenate-numpy-ndarray-like-objects-for-sequential-reading; this is from a list of [h5py] questions that I've answered.  You could search other users.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot! It's indeed the same question, and there seems to be no known solution :/. For now I'll stick with index transformations to transform an imaginary index into the overall dataset to a relative index into the respective dataset that contains the element of interest.

Comment: I would read the pointers in one list (as you have done more a less already). For acessing the actual data i would write a small wrapper. I'm a bit in a hurry now, but maybe I can post tomorrow a small wrapper which does what you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 have introduced the concept of a "Virtual Dataset (VDS)".
However, this does not work for versions before 1.10.

I have no experience with the VDS feature but the [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/vds.html) docs go into more detail and the h5py git repository has an example file [here](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/vds_simple.py) :

```
'''A simple example of building a virtual dataset.
This makes four 'source' HDF5 files, each with a 1D dataset of 100 numbers.
Then it makes a single 4x100 virtual dataset in a separate file, exposing
the four sources as one dataset.
'''

import h5py
import numpy as np

# Create source files (1.h5 to 4.h5)
for n in range(1, 5):
    with h5py.File('{}.h5'.format(n), 'w') as f:
        d = f.create_dataset('data', (100,), 'i4')
        d[:] = np.arange(100) + n

# Assemble virtual dataset
layout = h5py.VirtualLayout(shape=(4, 100), dtype='i4')

for n in range(1, 5):
    filename = "{}.h5".format(n)
    vsource = h5py.VirtualSource(filename, 'data', shape=(100,))
    layout[n - 1] = vsource

# Add virtual dataset to output file
with h5py.File("VDS.h5", 'w', libver='latest') as f:
    f.create_virtual_dataset('data', layout, fillvalue=-5)
    print("Virtual dataset:")
    print(f['data'][:, :10])
```

More details can be found on the [HDF group](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesVirtualDatasetDocs.html#Overview) which links to a [pdf](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/VDS/HDF5-VDS-requirements-use-cases-2014-12-10.pdf). Figure 1 illustrates the idea nicely.

Comment: I have looked into this a bit more since. Virtual datasets will not be available in `h5py` until 2.9. However, the version on the git master branch can be used to run the example.